# Only one ajax script works while I have two

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got two loadmore scripts that each are called by different buttons. But the second button loads the content that should be loaded by the first button, while the first button works fine.

This is how my html setup is (only the relevant code without the php inside etcetera)

```
<div class="row" id="loadprojects">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5" id="loadmoreprojects">
        <a href="javascript:;"><button class="btn btn-info">Bekijk meer projecten</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="loadnews">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5" id="loadmore">
        <a href="javascript:;"><button class="btn btn-info">Bekijk meer websites</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the footer these scripts are loaded:

```
<script src="assets/js/loadmore.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/loadmore_projects.js"></script>
```

And these are my two scripts:

(loadmore.js)

```
/*
Meer websites laden
*/
var limit = 3;

$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    limit += 3;

    ajax();

});

var posts = document.getElementById('loadnews');

function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmore.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {limit: limit},
    success: function(data){
        loadnews.innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Time out error.');
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   alert('Ajax request aborted.');
               } else {
                   alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
               }
           }
    }); 
}

ajax();
```

(loadmore_projects.js)

```
/*
Meer projecten laden
*/
var limit = 4;

$('#loadmoreprojects').click(function() {
    limit += 4;

    ajax();

});

var posts1 = document.getElementById('loadprojects');

function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmore_projects.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {limit: limit},
    success: function(data){
        loadprojects.innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Time out error.');
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   alert('Ajax request aborted.');
               } else {
                   alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
               }
           }
    }); 
}

ajax();
```

I checked all names, why is it that when I click on the second button, the first script is initiated? And not the correct one that has the same id in it as the button.

Comment: if these are the full files your problem is you are declaring everything in global scope, one is going to overwrite the other. Meaning `limit` from `loadmore.js` is going to be overwritten by `limit` in `loadmore_projects.js`, same goes for your `ajax()` function

Comment: @PatrickEvans Alright makes sense, been a while since I used this code. ajax(); is called before the function so I guess that's a property name instead of a function name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation.

To avoid variables overriding we can use immidiatly invoke function declaration like this:

```
(function(){}(
..code goes there
));
```

Because all functions have their own visibility scope, variable from other function will not see this variables and will not override them. 
Also you can improve your code adding 'use strict' mode to make your code behavior more clear. 
Just write  smth like this:

```
(function(){}(
'use strict';

..code goes there
));
```

Try yto always wrap your code with functions to avoid using global variables.

Try use such variant:

```
(function(){
/*
Meer websites laden
*/
var limit = 3;

$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    limit += 3;

    ajax();

});

var posts = document.getElementById('loadnews');

function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmore.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {limit: limit},
    success: function(data){
        loadnews.innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Time out error.');
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   alert('Ajax request aborted.');
               } else {
                   alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
               }
           }
    }); 
}

ajax();
}());

(function(){
/*
Meer projecten laden
*/
var limit = 4;

$('#loadmoreprojects').click(function() {
    limit += 4;

    ajax();

});

var posts1 = document.getElementById('loadprojects');

function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmore_projects.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {limit: limit},
    success: function(data){
        loadprojects.innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Time out error.');
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   alert('Ajax request aborted.');
               } else {
                   alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
               }
           }
    }); 
}

ajax();
}());
```

Comment: Edited. try once more.

Comment: Thanks it worked! What does wrapping it in (function()) do?

Comment: Ill edit once more my code for small explanation. Ok?

Comment: This is a very limited answer. Could you explain what you want the OP to do? And personally, wrapping the code in a scope is not the most elegant way to fix the op's problem

Comment: No problem, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining two functions with same name ajax(), change one of them.

Comment: or wrap them in an iife.